# Crash of packaged game “Assertion failed: SchemaIt != SchemaEnd” Unreal Engine 5 Preview

Tags: c++, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine5

It only happens with the packaged game. In editor, the game is running without any issues.

Please find the crash log for the same below,

```
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]Message dialog closed, result: Ok, title: The UE5-Demo_Store Game has crashed and will close, text: Assertion failed: SchemaIt != SchemaEnd [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Serialization\UnversionedPropertySerialization.cpp] [Line: 669] 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogThreadingWindows: Error: Runnable thread FAsyncLoadingThread crashed.
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: Assertion failed: SchemaIt != SchemaEnd [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\CoreUObject\Private\Serialization\UnversionedPropertySerialization.cpp] [Line: 669] 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9a71003 Demo_Store.exe!SerializeUnversionedProperties() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9a706b3 Demo_Store.exe!UScriptStruct::SerializeItem() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9be43b6 Demo_Store.exe!FStructProperty::SerializeItem() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9a71068 Demo_Store.exe!SerializeUnversionedProperties() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9a6ac98 Demo_Store.exe!UClass::SerializeDefaultObject() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7ade3ffd3 Demo_Store.exe!UBlueprintGeneratedClass::SerializeDefaultObject() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a82c9b92 Demo_Store.exe!UClass::SerializeDefaultObject() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a99717c3 Demo_Store.exe!FAsyncPackage2::EventDrivenSerializeExport() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9978bf0 Demo_Store.exe!FAsyncPackage2::Event_ProcessExportBundle() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a997c823 Demo_Store.exe!FEventLoadNode2::Execute() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9996526 Demo_Store.exe!FAsyncLoadEventQueue2::PopAndExecute() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a99b57e4 Demo_Store.exe!FAsyncLoadingThread2::Run() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a9891ceb Demo_Store.exe!FRunnableThreadWin::Run() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff7a988abf0 Demo_Store.exe!FRunnableThreadWin::GuardedRun() []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3b2254e0 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ffb3c98485b ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:755][  0]LogWindows: Error: Crash in runnable thread FAsyncLoadingThread
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:763][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:763][  0]LogWindows: FPlatformMisc::RequestExit(1)
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:763][  0]LogWindows: FPlatformMisc::RequestExitWithStatus(1, 3)
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:763][  0]LogCore: Engine exit requested (reason: Win RequestExit)
[2022.03.12-07.46.58:780][  0]Log file closed, 03/12/22 13:16:58
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be crashing here:

```
for (FUnversionedHeader::FIterator It(Header, Schema); It; It.Next())
{
  if (It.IsNonZero())
  {
     It.GetSerializer() /*...*/
  }
}
```

...

```
FUnversionedPropertySerializer GetSerializer() const
{
    check(SchemaIt != SchemaEnd);
    return *SchemaIt;
}
```

but I don't understand how the check can fail because in that loop `SchemaIt` can't equal `SchemaEnd`, so I'm confused.

Might want to report this as a bug to Epic.  https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/support/report-a-bug

Comment: Oh wait I'm looking at 4.72.2 code.  Might want to check that code in 5.0 preview 1 to see if it has changed.\

Answer (score 0):

debug packaged build of win or android,see the log to locate the asset's name cause this crash

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).